# Qt subclassed graphics scene does not allow me select/focus to graphics item on it

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have subclassed my own qgraphicsview because i wanted to send signals from scene with positions when clicked, on this scene are also my sublclassed graphics itms which are selectable and focusable. The problem is, when i implement my own mousepressed/mousemoved/mousereleased event handlers into the scene, I suddenly cannot select anything in the scene.

Here's my implementation of the graphics scene:

```
/////////////////////HEADER//////////////
#include <QGraphicsScene>

class myGraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit myGraphicsScene(QObject * parent = 0);
   explicit myGraphicsScene(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, QObject * parent = 0);

signals:
   void mouseReleased(QPointF pos);
   void mousePressed(QPointF pos);
   void mouseMoved(QPointF pos);
   void mouseDoubleClicked(QPointF pos);

protected:
   void mouseDoubleClickEvent (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event);
   void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event);
   void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event);
   void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event);


 ////////////////////CPP//////////////////////
 #include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>


 myGraphicsScene::myGraphicsScene(QObject *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent)
 {
 }

 myGraphicsScene::myGraphicsScene(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, QObject *parent)
    : QGraphicsScene( x, y, width, height, parent )
 {
 }

 void myGraphicsScene::mouseDoubleClickEvent ( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event )
 {
     QGraphicsScene::mouseDoubleClickEvent ( event );
     emit mouseDoubleClicked ( event->scenePos () );
 }

 void myGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
 {
    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent ( event );
    emit mousePressed ( event->scenePos () );
 }

 void myGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
 {
    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent ( event );
    emit mouseMoved ( event->scenePos () );
 }

 void myGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
 {
    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent ( event );
    emit mouseReleased ( event->scenePos () );
 }
```

**Which event implementation is wrong?**

P.S.: When i comment out the mousePressed/moved/released implementations it works like charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that calling events such as QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent, when called like this, may be setting the event to being handled. As QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent states for the [accepted](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qevent.html#accepted-prop) flag: -

> *Setting the accept parameter indicates that the event receiver wants the event. Unwanted events might be propagated to the parent widget. **By default, isAccepted() is set to true**, but don't rely on this as subclasses may choose to clear it in their constructor.*

You could try calling event->setAccepted(false) in each of the overloaded events to signal the event to be propagated.